# Windows 2008 R2 slow network data transfer using WCF app

Tags: windows, wcf, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2

We have WCF service running on IIS 7 under Windows 2008R2. We need to transfer files from the local machine to network shared path in another machine. We used the normal Copy/Move api in .NET for file copy/Move. It works fine, however transfer is too slow. Our dev machines its very fast.

We check other apps like SVN, also too slow. Seems TCP trnsfer is slow.

Any idea on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer.

We executed the following commands and works fine

(a) netsh interface tcp set global chimney=disabled

(b) netsh interface tcp set global rss=disabled

(c) netsh interface tcp set global autotuning=disabled

Additional links:

http://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=7002232

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2675785